# C++ Equivalent of strncpy

Tags: c++, string

What is the equivalent of `strncpy` in C++? `strncpy` works in C, but fails in C++.

This is the code I am attempting:

```
string str1 = "hello"; 
string str2; 
strncpy (str2,str1,5);
```

Comment: `strncpy` works just fine in C++. How are you using it?  Show us the code.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't fail in C++ unless you're doing it wrong.

Comment: When you say it "fails", what do you mean?  Compile error?  Link error?  Doesn't give the expected result?  Program crashes?

Comment: Can we see some example code? strncpy shouldn't simply fail in C++... I've definitely used it before.

Comment: string str1 = "hello"; string str2; strncpy (str2,str1,5); doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please post a whole block of code and the error, not one line.

Comment: @kay  strncpy takes char *'s as arguments.  In your example, str1 and str2 are not char *'s.

Comment: @kay: Incorporated your comments in to your post.  Please do this yourself in the future when you wish to clarify your questions.

Answer (score 11):

The equivalent of C's [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) (which, BTW, is spelled [`std::strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) in C++, and is to found in the header `<cstring>`) is `std::string`'s assignment operator:

```
std::string s1 = "Hello, world!";
std::string s2(s1);            // copy-construction, equivalent to strcpy
std::string s3 = s1;           // copy-construction, equivalent to strcpy, too
std::string s4(s1, 0, 5);      // copy-construction, taking 5 chars from pos 0, 
                               // equivalent to strncpy
std::string s5(s1.c_str(), std::min(5,s1.size())); 
                               // copy-construction, equivalent to strncpy
s5 = s1;                       // assignment, equivalent to strcpy
s5.assign(s1, 5);              // assignment, equivalent to strncpy
```

Comment: Copy construction needs to use the `string(const char*, size_t)` form in order to be the equivelant of `strncpy`

Comment: @John Dibling: Still no, that `string(const char*, size_t)` constructor doesn't stop at the first null encountered which is potentially dangerous for something returned by `c_str()`. @sbi: Should be `s5.assign(s1, 0, 4);` except that this sufferers from a similar issue (applies if `s1` contains a null character).

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for pointing this out. `<sigh>` I fixed this, too. Both should be _5_, not _4_, since I actually wanted to capture the whole first word, but forgot to fix the second example when I discovered that the first was wrong... According to 21.3.1/5, the ctor taking a length will stop when the string is smaller than the size given.

Comment: @sbi: For `string( const std::string&, size_t, size_t )`, yes; for `string( const char *, size_t )`, no (21.3.1/8). That was my reading.

Comment: @Charles: That's my reading, too, now that I looked it up. I was referring to your comment re `s5.assign(s1, 0, 4)`: "except that this sufferers from a similar issue". If `s1` contains a `'\0'` character, `s1` isn't an equivalent of a C string anymore, which is what the OP seems to be asking for, so I chose to assume no `'\0'` chars.

Comment: -1 Most of the information in this answer is incorrect. Copy construction and assignment from `std::string` objects are equivalent to `memmove`, not `strcpy`, because `strcpy` copies until the first NUL character is reached. Also, the second "strncpy equivalent" needs to use `min` instead of `max` and does not need to invoke the `c_str` member (which may actually create a new copy of the internal array).

Comment: @sbi: Yes, that's a fair point. The corner cases depend on one's assumptions and definitions up to a point.

Comment: @Daniel: When coming from C strings to `std::string`, ctor and asignop _are_ what you need to use instead of `strcpy()`. That they do more (namely be able to deal with strings containing zeros) doesn't invalidate this. As for `max()` vs. `min()`... `<sigh>` I've posted lots of stupid things on SO today. Anyway, I now fixed that. And that ctor does indeed take a `const char*`, not a `std::string`, so the `c_str()` is needed. See 21.3.1/6.

Comment: @sbi: "And that ctor does indeed take a `const char*`, not a `std::string`, so the `c_str()` is needed." You're right. Perhaps you could use the (const std::string&, size_type, size_type, Allocator) constructor: `std::string s5(s1, 0, std::min(5, s1.size()));`

Comment: @Daniel: In fact, I _do_ use this ctor. It's `s4`. `std::min()` isn't needed for this. See 21.3.1/5.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [basic_string::copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2177ss0.aspx) on a `std::string` version of your `const char*`, or use [std::copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9f6s1wf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which can use pointers as the input iterators.

What do you mean by "strncpy fails in C++", by the way?

Comment: You can't use `std::copy` without a bit of fancy footwork in order to incorporate the `n` in `strncpy`

Comment: @John - yes, in general moving to std::string and using member functions is preferable

Answer (score 3):

`strncpy` works on characters array, and it works just fine in C++ as well as in C.
If you are using `strncpy` with characters array in C++, and it doesn't work, it's probably because of some error in your C++ code: show us if you want some help.

If what you are looking for is a way to copy strings (ie: `std::string`), string's copy constructor or assignment operator will do what you're looking for:

```
std::string a = "hello!";
```

---

This will copy the whole string without any risk of buffer overflow. Anyway, as John Dibling says in the comments, it doesn't supply the same semantics of `strncpy`: it doesn't let you specify how many characters to copy.

If you need to copy up to a certain number of characters there are other ways: `std::string` offers a constructor that copier up to `n` characters, or you could use the other ways proposed in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

[strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) does not take `std::string` as arguments. The prototype is

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

and the provided link gives a description and example on how to use it.

I would stick with [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) but if you have to, then use `c_str()` `std::string` method to obtain the `char *` pointer

Answer (score 0):

strncpy is available from the `cstring header` in C++. Because it is C specific function with you have to deal with C kind of strings only, that is character arrays, not the string objects of C++

```
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
   char *s,*v;
   strncpy(s,v,0);
}
```

The above will compile properly, but will serve no useful purpose.
When you are using C++, try to use the `string` objects and its copy method of assignment operator to assign to a different string. Copy method takes a parameter where you can specify the number of characters to copy to the target string object.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent of `strncpy` in C++ is `strncpy`.

You're just doing something wrong in your code, please post your code and the error.

Comment: This should be a comment. And you'd see that plenty of people already thought the same thing and posted one. Upvote one of theirs if you agree.

Comment: Sorry, when I saw the question I immediately started to answer, and got interrupted midway. When I posted the answer the comments were there :)